# Have some content at the bottom of the last page

Tags: html, css, pdf, footer

I'm making a page that is turned into a PDF. This PDF will be multiple pages long. I want to have some text content like the terms and conditions at the bottom of only the last page of the PDF generated.

Currently I am using `.footer`, but this prints the text at the bottom of every page.

```
<HTML>
    <head>
        <style>
            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                clear:both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            Main content
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            Footer Content. I want this to be only on the last page.
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are you using the print method of the browser to create the PDF?

Comment: make a template with the footer on just for the last page content - if the content is fixed.

Comment: How are you "printing to PDF"? Have you tried CSS media queries. Specifically the "print" media type.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just making the last page separate from the others. So export your PDF without the last page then go in and edit the last page then just add it to the final PDF. You can do so with any free PDF editor.
Heres a link to one thats online so no need to download anything  [LINK](https://pdf-editor-online.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwpeXeBRA6EiwAyoJPKkurjQ_qkkKAgtuSKQx1UuKEPasUmMYm_aPZrj_05rAOvfjb6SPKtxoCEEsQAvD_BwE)